# FTPWebRequest reading file on server and return list of filename

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I created a method that enable to read all filename from FTP Server with extension of *.xml and return an array of string filename.  But I'm getting some error "The given Path's format is not supported.."    Here is the code snippet:

```cs
protected static string[] FTPRelativePaths(string[] filelist)
{
    if (null == filelist)
        return new string[0];

    string[] result = new string[filelist.Length];
    for (int index = 0; index < filelist.Length; ++index)
        result[index] = Path.GetFileName(filelist[index]);

    return result;
}

public static string[] GetFileList(Uri serverUri, string ftpUserID,
    string ftpPassword)
{
     // The serverUri parameter should start with the ftp:// scheme.
     if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
     {
         return null;
     }

     string[] fileList= new string[0];
     try
     {
         WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
         FtpWebRequest ftprequest =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
         //ftprequest.UseBinary = true;
         ftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
         ftprequest.Credentials =new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
         FtpWebResponse response = ftprequest.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
         string ext = "*.xml";
         string[] foundfiles = FTPRelativePaths(
             Directory.GetFiles(serverUri.ToString(), ext));

         if (foundfiles.Length > 0)
         {
             string[] newlist = new string[foundfiles.Length];
             foundfiles.CopyTo(newlist, fileList.Length);
             fileList = newlist;
             System.Array.Sort(fileList);
         }

         response.Close();
         return fileList;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         fileList = null;
         return fileList;
     }
 }
```

Once i got all filenames in an array i will bind this into ComboBox sitesXmlCombo object,  like this:

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);               
string[] xmlFiles = FileList.GetFileList(uri, "username", "password");

sitesXmlCombo.DataSource = xmlFiles;
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
```

How can I accomplish this?  I appreciate for your help...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error on Uri; try with this:

```
string _remoteHost = "ftp://ftp.name.com/htdocs/directory/";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_remoteHost));
```